# Equivalent of Navigator Arguments in Flutter Go Router

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router, gorouter

What will be equivalent of the below Flutter Navigator in terms of Go Router?

```dart
    Navigator.pushNamed(
       context,
       Routes.CHANNEL_PAGE,
       arguments:ChannelPageArgs(
         channel:channel,
          initialMessage:message,
        ),
    );
```

Usually Go Router is based on parameters from the path. But the above example is based on a object instead of primitive parameters.

```dart
        GoRoute(
          path: '/profile/:id',
          builder: (context, state) => ProfilePage(id: state.params['id']!),
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can pass  object as an `extra` like this:

```html
final args = ChannelPageArgs(
     channel:channel,
      initialMessage:message,
    )
context.pushNamed('profile', extra: args)
```

in your goRouter:

```html
      GoRoute(
              path: 'profile',
              name: 'profile',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                final args = state.extra as ChannelPageArgs;
                return MaterialPage(
                  key: state.pageKey,
                  child: ProfilePage(
                    args: args,
                  ),
```

Answer (score 5):

### Summary:

There are three ways `params`,`queryParams`,`extra`

1. Using `params`

   - When you know the number of parameters beforehand
   - Usage : `path = '/routeName/:id1/:id2'`
2. Using `queryParams`

   - When you are not sure about the number of parameters
   - Usage : `path = '/routeName'`
3. Using `extra`

   - When you want to pass `object`

### Explanation:

#### 1. Using `Params`

If you want to add a `name` parameter in the `settings` route, the path argument should be `/settings:name`. You can access the route parameter with the `state.params["name"] variable`.

###### Define it as:

```
 GoRoute(
    path: "/settings/:name",
    builder: (context, state) => SettingsPage(
      name: state.params["name"]!,
    ),
 );
```

###### Receive it as:

```
 class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;

  const SettingsPage({super.key, required this.name});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

#### 2. Using `queryParams`

You have access to `queryParams` in the `context.goNamed()` function. The best thing about `queryParams` is that you don't have to explicitly define them in your route path and can easily access them using the `state.queryParams` method. You can add miscellaneous user-related data as a query parameter.

##### Add Parameters like so

```
child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => context.goNamed("settings", 
  queryParams: {
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "age": "25",
    "place": "India"
    }),
    child: const Text("Go to Settings page"),
),
```

##### Receive it as :

```
GoRoute(
  name: "settings",
  path: "settings",
  builder: (context, state) {
    state.queryParams.forEach(
      (key, value) {
        print("$key:$value");
       },
     );
   return SettingsPage();
 },
)
```

#### 3. Using `extra`

```
 GoRoute(
    path: '/sample',
    builder: (context, state) {
      Sample sample = state.extra as Sample; // -> casting is important
      return GoToScreen(object: sample);
    },
  ),
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74813017/13431819 for passing `object` between routes.